# show checkbox instead of 1 and 0 in drupal 8 table

Tags: drupal-8, theming

I would really appreciate you to help me with this.
The problem is: I'm trying to show a checkbox on each row depending on the value of an entity field, more or less like this

```
$row['access'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#value' => $entity->getAccess()
];
```

But none of that has worked, and I can't find almost any documentation on how to do such thing. please help me

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, what I ended up doing was a custom template, just as suggested by previous comments. But, instead of using the `EntityListBuilder` I made a custom controller that rendered the custom template passing the entity array as a variable. Thank you very much, all your suggestions were a lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the EntityListBuilder::render function and override the  table.html.twig template.

Comment: I'm actually not using a view. The code I provided is inside a `buildRow` method inside an `EntityListBuilder` class. Should I make a custom template in my module to display my table or something like that?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Any idea on how should I override the template? I've already used the `render` method, but that neither worked.

Answer (score -1):

You can use twig and theme suggestion to theme your field, override the template and theme the field depends on the state.

To override the template you could do that by [theme-suggestion](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/working-with-twig-templates)

To theme your field [That can help you](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254491/how-to-check-a-boolean-value-in-twig-templates?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Another thing :[Debugging Twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates)

With the @Steve Mulvihill's reply, I think you can do the job :)

Hope that helped you...

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try your solution and soon I will let you know if it works :)

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, I'm really new to Drupal. The thing is, I cant override a template, because I also need to use `tableselect` in my `$build['table']['#type']. Besides that, I need to add filters in the table, so, I'm not really sure if my problems get solved by overriding the template.

Comment: You can use the template array to theme your table. 
one of links I suggested is about theming array theme :)

happy you've done what you want :)